# Will splitting a form using jQuery UI Tabs affect the posting of the form to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, jquery-ui-tabs

Will splitting up the `<form></form>` using the jQuery UI tabs() method affect the posting of the form to PHP?

Such as:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
  $('#Tabs').tabs();
 </script>
 <form method="post" action="form.php" >
   <div id="Tabs">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#content1">content1</a>
       <li><a href="#content2">content2</a>
    </ul>
   <div id="#content1>
      <input type="text" name="field1" />
    </div>
   <div id="content2">
     <input type="content'' name="field2" />
     <input type="sumbit" /></div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Best way is to try it out. But I don't belief PHP will have a problem. But then again we don't know what you want to achieve

Comment: input type `submit` not `sumbit` and close input's correctly

Comment: No, but your bad HTML marlup will

Comment: sorry someone was disturbing while typing this

Answer (score 1):

No. The form will still contain all of the `<input>` elements, even if they're not currently visible. As such they'll all be submitted when the form is.

However, there's an issue with your example, in that the jQuery code will execute before the `<div id="Tags">` element exists. Wrap it in a document ready call:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Tabs').tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: <script>$(function() { $('#Tabs').tabs(); });</script> will work too ??

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Yes, that's just a shorter way of doing the same thing.